# Interpreting patterns in the residual plot from OLS regression

Tags: least-squares, residuals

Below are some residual plots from an OLS regression. The dependent variable is quality of life in patients measured on the 0-1 scale and independent variables are a mix of continuous and categorical variables including e.g., age, age^2, gender, smoker and medications used, measured once per patient.

The dependent variable is in turn created by applying a linear function on a descriptive system used to measure health in patients, consisting of five dimensions: mobility, self-care, usual activities, pain/discomfort and anxiety/depression. Each dimension has 3 levels: no problems, some problems, and extreme problems.

What might be causing the patterns detected in the residual plots and what can I do to fix these? Also, since the dependent variable is bounded between 0-1, what might be a better approach than OLS if predictions are of interest? 
[image]

Comment: Hint: points with any particular observed response $k$ must lie on a line residual $= k -$ fitted in the top left plot. Hence expect to see stripes with slope $-1$.

Comment: Exactly what Nick Cox said - if you have an ordered categorical response, this is what you expected when you fit with OLS. More appropriate would be an ordinal regression.